# Prestashop 1.5 sort product in catgory page by price lowest to heighest by default

Tags: prestashop

this question can be silly to you, but i am having trouble to find a solution. I want to sort product in category  page by price lowest to highest, i know there is drop by which i can see products by price but i want to set it by default so that page loads with sorted. can you tell which file i should modify? and how can i achieve this?

here is the url so you can check which things i am talking about:

`http://pinstripecreative.com/nationalcapp2/5-decaffeinated`

Answer (score 0):

For people who are meeting such issue in Prestashop 1.6, the default sort type can be set in backend via preferences> Products > Set default sorting.

Note that some default modules, like blocksearch, can force the sorting of page by sending the `orderby` and `orderway` via a hidden input. Then you need in this case to change the view by either deleting the inputs or sending your own `orderby` and `orderway`.

[Products default sort not working on search.tpl - Prestashop 1.6.0.6 - Resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718666/products-default-sort-not-working-on-search-tpl-prestashop-1-6-0-6-resolved/24726882#24726882)