# Products default sort not working on search.tpl - Prestashop 1.6.0.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I set up in backoffice the default sort type to : in stock. this works for all pages except SearchController template file : search.tpl.

What can be the causes behind such dysfunctionning? I really don't know what part of code to deal with. Thanks everyone who already met such issue for advices.

**Edit:**
I discovered that the link in the adress bar after click on search button is:

```
 website/index.phpcontroller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=design+40&submit_search=Rechercher
```

When I remove `orderby=position&orderway=desc`, the default behaviour works. I just need to remove this action from controller but still don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template file, I found:

```
<form method="get" action="{$link->getPageLink('search')|escape:'html'}" id="searchbox">
        <p>
            <label for="search_query_top"><!-- image on background --></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search" />
            <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="quantity" />
            <input type="hidden" name="orderway" value="desc" />
            <input class="search_query" type="text" id="search_query_top" name="search_query" value="{$search_query|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|stripslashes}" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit_search" value="{l s='Search' mod='blocksearch'}" class="button" />
        </p>
</form>
```

As you see, I have already changed the value of the hidden input to `quantity`. Hope it helps.